# iAd UICollectionView on every 5 cell

Tags: swift, xcode

This is my first time to use iAd and want to display it on every 5 cell in UICollectionView. I have two cells one normal and one for iAd, I have connected delegate to the IAdCell and ref to ADBannerViewDelegate

In the viewDidLoad() I have self.canDisplayBannerAds = true

In the UICollectionView I use this code to decide what cell I want to return

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

```
    let isBanner = movies[indexPath.row].TmdbId == nil
    if(isBanner){
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("iAdCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! IAdCell

        return cell
    }

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LatestMovieTVCell

    return cell
}
```

The cell looks like this

import UIKit
import iAd

class IAdCell : UICollectionViewCell, ADBannerViewDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet var IAdBanner: ADBannerView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    IAdBanner.hidden = true
}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    banner.hidden = false
}

func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

}

But it seems not to display the ad it is empty

Thanks
Bennie

Answer (score 3):

Apple shut down the iAd network:

https://developer.apple.com/support/iad/

> Starting July 1, 2016, iAd will no longer be available for developers to earn revenue by running ads sold by iAd or promote their apps on the iAd App Network.

All the `iAd.framework` stuff is deprecated. That's why you're not seeing anything.

> Apps that have implemented the deprecated iAd.Framework classes should not crash solely because of the deprecation. On your next regular app update or submission, you should remove the iAd framework and connection.